# Separating IdentityUser from UserProfile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I split my user-details into it's own table **Profile** with a foreign key to the ApplicationUser, but now my inserts fail.

So I got the following tables:

```
AspNetUsers 
{
    Id
    UserName
    PasswordHash
    SecurityStamp
    Descriminator
}
```

and

```
Profiles
{
    Id
    FirstName
    LastName
    Email
    AspNetUser_Id
}
```

So I changed the **RegisterViewModel** by adding the extra fields like this:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string EMail { get; set; }
}
```

... and incorporated the fields from the Profiles table into the **Register.cshtml** and I want to store the information from the model into the two tables. So my AccountController.Register looks like this:

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var profile = new Profile
                {
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.LastName,
                    EMail = model.EMail,
                    User = user
                };

                var db = new DecoupleDb();
                db.Profiles.Add(profile);
                db.SaveChanges();

                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }
```

But now I keep getting an error on the

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

the error saying Im trying to violate the Primary key of the AspNetUsers table

"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.AspNetUsers'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetUsers'. The duplicate key value is (372775e0-bad5-452f-b65c-cd9bf7b80b34).
The statement has been terminated."

And I cant understand why, because it's only a foreign key so when I add the Profile the AspNetUser should not be created, or so I thought.

Anyone see a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I have to store the new user, then fetch it back and populate the Profile.
Like this:

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser {UserName = model.UserName};
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var newUser = db.ApplicationUsers.Find(user.Id);

                var profile = new Profile
                {
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.LastName,
                    Email = model.Email,
                    Identity = newUser,
                };

                db.Profiles.Add(profile);
                db.SaveChanges();

                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }
```

Comment: this is not a good answer. What if network fails during the process? You will lose second part of transaction

Comment: I found the answer, you need to do  YourDbContext dbContext = Request.GetOwinContext().Get<YourDbContext >(); and that will get you current DB context and allow fetch virtual properties without context adding them